# What is the correct word order and punctuation when using "however" + "initially"?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, punctuation

> However, initially it was just a way of spending my free time.

Is this sentence correct? Or maybe I should say:

> Initially, however, it was just a way of spending my free time?

or

> However, initially it was just a way of spending my free time.

Comment: Both of your choices are "correct". Without more context, though, we can't say anything more. Please read our [**Details, Please**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post. It will help you write a better question.

Answer (score 1):

> However, initially it was just a way of spending my free time.

This is grammatically correct.

> Initially, however, it was just a way of spending my free time

This is grammatically correct.

Then what is the difference between the two sentences?

They are very similar. The first word appears to get slightly more emphasis than the second word, so if more weight should be on "initially", place it at the beginning. If more emphasis should be on "however", place it at the beginning.

Comment: @HonzaZidek , updated